# Prepared statement in OOP

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I'm new to OOP in PHP so please be kind.

I've included the code for both files. I get an error of unidentified variable $conn.
The include file is already included on the page that's piecing it together so I'm not sure why this isn't working. Any ideas?

dbh.inc.php

```
<?php

class dbh {
    
    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;
    
    protected function connect() {
        $this->servername = "localhost";
        $this->username = "root";
        $this->password= "";
        $this->dbname = "template_website";
        
        $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);
        
        return $conn;
    }
}
```

page.inc.php

```
<?php

class page extends Dbh {
    
    protected function getPage() {
        $sql = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_url=?
        ");

        $sql->bind_param("s",$_GET["page_url"]);
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->get_result();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
            $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
        }
        else {
            echo "fml";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$sql = $conn->prepare(...)` Where did you define `$conn` ?

Comment: defined in dbh.inc.php. Included on the display page before page.inc.php

Comment: Take some time to learn more about [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: It's actually local to the method `connect()`, and therefore not available from outside of its scope